# I run the code below and I following error: Undefined variable: expression in

Tags: php, tags

Example #1 Advanced escaping using conditions
http://www.php.net/manual/ro/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

This is the code:
    
      This will show if the expression is true.
    
      Otherwise this will show.

Comment: Where is the code and the link to the manual ??

Comment: @ionut stop breaking the fixes other people make to your question, or use the toolbar to set the paragraph as code.

Comment: @dystroy or you could let them edit their own question. Editing someone else's question that's less than 5 minutes old is just making it difficult for the author to correct the mistakes they see when it's published.

Comment: I've let him edit the question, that's why I mentioned how to fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

> I don't understand why in the php manual from site php, say this works.

It works if you have assigned a value to `$expression` in the first place (and it is generally reasonable to assume that you will before you test it).

> `@$expression`

Don't suppress errors. Avoid them

> `isset($expression)`

Yes. If `$expression` isn't guaranteed to be set, test if it is set before performing other tests on it.

Comment: I began to understand therefore must define $expression = 'something here', before the statement "if". Otherwise I have this error: "Undefined variable: expression in ...".
@ Symbol before the variable is used for testing, and expression isset ($ expression) is used to avoid errors.

Answer (score -3):

They say that if $expression is set to true, the if statement is executed, and if $expression isn't set to true, the else statement is executed...

So your code must looks like this:

```
<?php $expression = true; // true for if statement, false for else statement ?>
<?php if ($expression == true): ?>
  This will show if the expression is true.
<?php else: ?>
  Otherwise this will show.
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I won't downvote because I'm not able to understand the question either but I doubt this is an answer.